# Read results from dynamically created list of ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm creating a dynamic array af ajax calls that I need to perform. So I do something like that:

```
        var requests = [];

        if (weNeedCustomerData) {
            var customerCallPromise = $.ajax(...);
            requests.push(customerCallPromise);
        }
        if (weNeedOrdersData) {
            var ordersCallPromise = $.ajax(...);
            requests.push(ordersCallPromise);
        }
        if (weNeedSalesData) {
            var salesCallPromise = $.ajax(...);
            requests.push(salesCallPromise);
        }

        $.when.apply(null, requests).done(function (result1, result2, result3) {
            ...
        });
```

And as long as all my "if" conditions are true, it's working good. I can get results of each call.

But how should I handle the situation where, for example, first "if" statement is false and I end up with just two requests? I'd have only two results in "done" method.

How can I read these results in a situation where I have no idea how many requests there will be so I have no idea how many argument the "done" function will have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store off or process the results individually:

```
    var requests = [], customerData, ordersData, salesData;

    if (weNeedCustomerData) {
        var customerCallPromise = $.ajax(...).done(function(result){
            customerData = result;
        });
        requests.push(customerCallPromise);
    }
    if (weNeedOrdersData) {
        var ordersCallPromise = $.ajax(...).done(function(result){
            ordersData = result;
        });
        requests.push(ordersCallPromise);
    }
    if (weNeedSalesData) {
        var salesCallPromise = $.ajax(...).done(function(result){
            salesData = result;
        });
        requests.push(salesCallPromise);
    }

    $.when.apply(null, requests).done(function () {
        //Here you know all relevant requests are complete
        if(customerData) {
            //...
        }
        //etc
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

uhm... i'm not sure if I understand your problem... but i think you not know much attributes has the `.done()` callback function (result1, result2, result3,...) because you not know how many condition was printed.

may you can use a cicle for check the attributes of callback function like:

```
var requests = [];
var _y = 0;

    if (weNeedCustomerData) {
        var customerCallPromise = $.ajax(...);
        //i guess $.ajax() is sync not async for use this syntax and not put the request store inside of the success callback.
        requests[_y] = customerCallPromise;
        _y++;
    }
    if (weNeedOrdersData) {
        var ordersCallPromise = $.ajax(...);
        requests[_y] = customerCallPromise;
        _y++;
    }
    if (weNeedSalesData) {
        var salesCallPromise = $.ajax(...);
        requests[_y] = customerCallPromise;
        _y++;
    }

$.when.apply(null, requests).done(function () {
    if(arguments.lenght > 0){
         for(var _k = 0; _k < arguments.lenght; k++){
             //this log show you all arguments (result1,resut2,result3...ecc...) whitout you need to define all
             console.log(arguments[_k]);
         }
    }
});
```

**but right now i have some perplexity about the ajax and the way that you used for evalue requests, because if $.ajax is async the script not wait for salesCallPromise evaluing... but maybe is only my paranoia**...

:) i hope it can help.

Comment: Yeah, that partially solves the problem. This will allow me to read the responses but still I will not know which argument stores a response to which request. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: you have a lot of way to order the response... i edit my answer with an examplre... teke me some minutes

Comment: Can you please replace 'attributes' with 'arguments'. I edited it but it got edited over before approved.

Comment: @johnnycardy thx... i cofused 'attributes' with 'arguments'... my bad (maybe I refused your edit in my code, but it's only an error, your edit is correct.) [sometimes i use a translate to help me with translation, end sometimes i suck] - Ottimo sei pure italiano xD

Comment: Ok, but still the responses are in the arguments array. Now let's say that I want to read the response of the "salesCallPromise". Depending on the initial "if" contitions, it will be either in arguments[0], arguments[1] or arguments[2].
I know that I can loop trough them but I need to know which one stores the response to which request so I can parse these responses and use them in further business logic.

Comment: the array's (argument) elements have all the information about the parent request, because they're jqXHR' Objects http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR, maybe you can use this information to identify them. Or inside your response you can to set an unique ID to identify the parent request (or what you need to)...

Answer (score 0):

1/ Well this is a tricky. You have control over server-side part of this code you can put flag/markers from which server-side action method comes the result. In the client (javascript ) you can switch this flag/marker.
 2/ The other and way and may be more appropriate is to see in When.js documentation how to handle this situation https://github.com/cujojs/when

Comment: That would work but in my case I have no control over the server responses.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to not use $.when - make clear $.ajax calls and process corresponding responses ;)

Comment: That also is an option but in that case I'd have to manually synchronize all that dynamic, asynchrous calls. Using $.when gives me that advantage that it will continue as soon as all the calls are back which is exactly what I need in there. Independent calls will be asynchrous and it won't be easy to find out when all of them are done.

Comment: Why it is easy ... again use flags in the client - one for each AJAX call which will mark completion of the corresponding call ;)